# How do I fix TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found

Tags: python-3.x

This is the code that I have and I am trying to fix TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found

The error I believe is when I try to open the file that is entered

```
def sendEmail():
    message = EmailMessage()
    sender = input("Please enter the email address of the sender: ")
    password = getpass.getpass("Please enter the password for the senders email: ")
    recipient = input("Please enter the email address of the recipient: ")
    subject = input("Please enter the subject of the email: ")
    compromisedUser = input("Please enter the username of the compromised user: ")
    mailServer = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com")
    mailServer.login(sender, password)
    # Email headers
    message["From: "] = sender
    message["To: "] = recipient
    message["Subject: "] = subject

    # body of the email
    body = """Hello,
    the following files and user have been compromised: """ "\nUser:" + compromisedUser
    message.set_content(body)

    # Send file with compromised files
    attach = input("Do you have a file to attach to the email? (Y or N): ")
    if attach.upper() == "Y":
        filename = input("Enter the file name of one of the compromised files: ")
        mime_type, _ = mimetypes.guess_type("filename")
        mime_type = mimetypes.MimeTypes().guess_type(filename)[0]
        print(mime_type)
        mime_type, mime_subtype = mime_type.split("/")
        with open(filename, "rb") as file:
            message.add_attachment(file.read(), maintype=mime_type, subtype=mime_subtype, filename=filename)
            mailServer.send_message(message)
            mailServer.quit()
    # if no file was sent then the body message is sent
    else:
         mailServer.send_message(message)
         mailServer.quit()
```